# How to remove High Performance Bedding (HPB) from the bottom of my raised garden bed without disturbing the surrounding interlocking?

Tags: raised-beds, drainage, gravel, pavers

I recently got my backyard interlocked and had a stone garden wall installed (6 feet long, 3 feet wide and 15 inches tall). The garden wall is surrounded by interlocking on 3 sides and a wall on the fourth side. The contractor used high performance bedding (HPB) as the base material and ended up filling the bottom of the raised garden with HPB. I believe they did it so it's easier for them to level the whole area. As I didn't know much about gardening then I didn't think it would be a big deal cause there is still 15" space left for garden soil and compost. Moreover the contractor told me that the gravel is useful for drainage. So I went along with their plan.

But now as I am looking up on ways to fill up this garden bed I have found out that many vegetables require deep roots for optimal growth and that filling the bottom of the garden bed with stones is actually bad for plants (e.g. [What "gotchas" should I avoid when building a raised garden?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/what-gotchas-should-i-avoid-when-building-a-raised-garden)). So I am thinking about removing the gravel and replacing it with top soil and organic material. The main concern I have is whether removing the gravel from the bottom of the raised bed would disturb the HPB and interlocking around the garden wall. I would assume that some of the HPB surrounding the garden wall (beneath the tiles) would fall into the empty space that I create by removing HPB from the garden bed floor. But If I replace the removed HPB with soil immediately I am hoping that this disturbance would be minimal ? Is that true ? Is there anything I can do to avoid disturbing the surrounding HPB ?

Comment: What is High Performance Bedding?  Is it crushed stone? Gravel?

Comment: Yes. It's crushed and cleaned up limestone in consistent size. See this https://www.dufferinaggregates.com/portfolio-item/hpb-tm-high-performance-bedding/